# Is it possible to develop a custom ALEPH client so that I do not have to use OPAC?

Tags: database, client, aleph

My university's library is using ALEPH 500 as the DB. And it has an old and not-mobile friendly website to query book info.

I recently learned that using tools like ODBC or JDBC, we can create websites and apps to connect to databases, such as MySQL.

This makes me thinking if ALEPH has any connection methods similar to this, that can be used to query information, so I can write some simple codes to make a mobile client for accessing the uni library DB.

Comment: ALEPH does not support ODBC, considering the security and integrity: https://knowledge.exlibrisgroup.com/Aleph/Knowledge_Articles/Does_Aleph_support_ODBC_connection%3F